# How to run scripts/commands on elastic beanstalk instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I have created instance using elastic bean stalk. I want to run some commands/scripts to start my application as it is simple java application. Please let me know how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can ssh to the ec2 instance using putty or terminal if you are linux user then, run the script in the ec2 instance. Make sure your script have proper permissions.

Comment: That requires manual intervention - okay for a one-off, but it defeats the object of Elastic Beanstalk where instances are started automatically as needed. Can you do it automatically at installation?

Comment: The question does not say in any way 'automatically'. The answer is correct. If you want automation of commands then use AWS OpsWorks.